# Why am I not seeing banner updates in Firefox?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-attributes

Hello this seems to be a new issue; I don't see the usual banner links in Firefox. I clear history and cookies and still, nothing. This happens on the different computers. 
However when I try it in Internet Explorer it seems fine.

Anyone has a similar issue? How do I fix this?

FIREFOX BANNER:
[image]

INTERNET EXPLORER BANNER:
[image]

Firefox HTML script contains the content but it is not being displayed:
[image]

Comment: Its fine for me in chrome but not in FF.  I have no idea.  Its possible I screwed something up when updating, but I've been over it and don't see it.

Comment: This is the first week this has happened but I don't know if it's facebook or some SE script. Hard to say since FF now updates so often. Can we elevate this to the SE developers?

Comment: well its marked as a bug, so it should go.

Comment: thanks.  it's showing up in the HTML script just not displaying in the browser for some reason. I will add that capture in the question as well.

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tool I apparently have in Firefox under Tools | Web Developer | Inspect (not sure if it's an extension or there by default in version 12) suggests that the banner text is being displayed below the picture (and then being overwritten by the page's content) instead of to the right:

[image]

Not that I have any idea *why* it's doing that.

Comment: Ah, I have an idea.

Comment: Is it fixed for you?

Comment: The content is simply too wide, so its wrapping. Shorten the length of the lines of text, and the problem should resolve itself.

Comment: @jrista thats what I did

Comment: @rfusca Yes, it's working for me, now.

Comment: good work people! and it corrects my czenglish title...

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the same thing happens to me in any browser if the zoom level is not at it's default. Try resetting your zoom to make sure you aren't zoomed in or out, and it should be fixed.